# Form validation not working in multiple records

Tags: php, jquery

What I have here is edit records from database. I put a form validation for security purposes. My script for form validation is working for 1 record only. But when I tried to edit 2 or more records the script isn't working for the other records. Only on the first record function my script. I need to validate all records.

Help please?

**Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register_form"  name="register_form" onsubmit="javascript:parent.location.reload(true);">

<p class="validate_msg">Please fix the errors below!</p>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
$id=$_POST['checkbox'];
$drop=$_POST['drop'];
$tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];

$drop=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$drop);
$tier_two=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$tier_two);

$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
SELECT a.item_name, a.item_description, a.counter, b.counter, b.pr, b.total_quantity
FROM app a
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_request b
ON a.counter=b.counter
WHERE a.counter='$id[$i]'
    ");
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
      { ?>
 <p> <label for="">ID</label> <input name="n_counter[]" type="text" id="n_counter" value="<?php echo $row['counter'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_counter"></span> </p>

 <p> <label for="">Item</label> <input name="n_itemname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_item"></span> </p>

 <p> <label for="">Description</label> <input name="n_itemdescription" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['item_description'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/><span class="val_desc"></span> </p>

 <p> <label for="">PR Quantity</label> <input name="n_quantity[]" id="n_quantity"  class="tb1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['total_quantity']; ?>" />
                <span class="val_qty"></span> </p>

 <p> <label for="">PR #</label> <input name="n_app_cn[]" id="n_app_cn" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['pr'] ?>" /><span class="val_project"></span> </p>    
    <br>
      <?php
      }
}

?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="sbtBtn" value="Update">
</form>
```

And this is my **Script**

```
<script>

    jQuery(function($) {
        var validation_holder;

        $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

        var validation_holder = 0;

            var project         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_app_cn']").val();
            var project_regex   = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check    

            var item            = $("form#register_form input[name='n_itemname']").val();
            var item_regex      = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check

            var desc            = $("form#register_form input[name='n_itemdescription']").val();
            var desc_regex      = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // reg ex cost check

            var qty             = $("form#register_form input[id='n_quantity']").val();
            var qty_regex       = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check

            var counter         = $("form#register_form input[id='n_counter']").val();
            var counter_regex   = /^[0-9]+$/; // reg ex qty check
            //var email_regex   = /^[\w%_\-.\d]+@[\w.\-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/; // reg ex email check    
            //var password      = $("form#register_form input[name='password']").val();
            //var repassword        = $("form#register_form input[name='repassword']").val();
            //var phone             = $("form#register_form input[name='phone']").val();
            //var phone_regex       = /^[0-9]{4,20}$/; // reg ex phone check    

            /* validation start */  

            if(project == "") {
                $("span.val_project").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;
            } else {
                if(!project_regex.test(project)){ // if invalid phone
                    $("span.val_project").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                    validation_holder = 1;

                } else {
                    $("span.val_project").html("");
                }
            }

            if(item == "") {
                $("span.val_item").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;
            } else {
                if(!item_regex.test(item)){ // if invalid phone
                    $("span.val_item").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                    validation_holder = 1;

                } else {
                    $("span.val_item").html("");
                }
            }

            if(desc == "") {
                $("span.val_desc").html("");
            } else {
                if(!desc_regex.test(desc)){ // if invalid phone
                    $("span.val_desc").html("Invalid Special Characters! Sucks").addClass('validate');
                    validation_holder = 1;

                } else {
                    $("span.val_desc").html("");
                }
            }

            if(qty == "") {
                $("span.val_qty").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;
            } else {
                if(!qty_regex.test(qty)){ // if invalid phone
                    $("span.val_qty").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
                    validation_holder = 1;

                } else {
                    $("span.val_qty").html("");
                }
            }

            if(counter == "") {
                $("span.val_counter").html("");
            } else {
                if(!counter_regex.test(counter)){ // if invalid phone
                    $("span.val_counter").html("Please Refresh to avoid database error!").addClass('validate');
                    validation_holder = 1;

                } else {
                    $("span.val_counter").html("");
                }
            }

            if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
                $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
                return false;
            }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
            /* validation end */    
        }); // click end 

    }); // jQuery End
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: @SurrealDreams no errors, just a warning.

Comment: @SurrealDreams please help me :/

Comment: Part of your problem is probably related to having non-unique ids.  An id should never be repeated in valid HTML.  When selecting an element by id, if there are multiple elements with that same id, JavaScript will typically behave as if there was only one.  It will find the first instance of an element with that id and ignore the rest.  You're better off with unique ids, and use classes to select multiple elements.  Also, the .val() method gets you the value of the first matched element from a set.

Comment: Not to discourage you from writing your own validation - it can be worth doing, both for learning and getting validation exactly the way you want it - but you may want to check out the [jQuery Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.  It's good for both basic and advanced validation.  If nothing else, it's full of good ideas and potential ideas on how to design your own.